# JobIntentService not call OnHandleWork

Tags: java, android, jobintentservice

I've custom ***JobIntentService*** witn static method *enqueueWork*.

```
public static void enqueueWork(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {        
            enqueueWork(context, MyJobIntentService.class, JOB_ID, intent);       
    }
```

Also I've  custom implementation of the FirebaseMessagingService. When I receive the push notification from FCM, I call the *enqueueWork* of my ***JobIntentService***.

```
MyJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, new Intent());
```

But method *OnHandleWork* ***not called on Android 8.0 and higher***.
My *manifest.xml*.

```
<service android:name="com.company.MyJobIntentService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Do you have any ideas why it work not correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing incorrectly. Unfortunately, JobIntentService will not run immediately on Android 8.0 and higher.

```
When running as a pre-O service, the act of enqueueing work will generally start the service immediately, regardless of whether the device is dozing or in other conditions. When running as a Job, it will be subject to standard JobScheduler policies for a Job with a setOverrideDeadline(long) of 0: the job will not run while the device is dozing, it may get delayed more than a service if the device is under strong memory pressure with lots of demand to run jobs.
```

When testing，I new a empty project, it runs immediately when call, but when i use in a real complex project，it runs several minutes later after called.